# Is there a method to place GameObjects in a grid pattern (similar to a tilemap)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to unity so sorry if I phrase this weirdly.

I'm trying to create a large area where each "tile" has a chance to spawn a random object. I have it working for a single empty GameObject, but making a large grid would require copy/pasting the same object over and over again and setting its position.

Answer (score 2):

Its on the [Official Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html):

> Placing a bunch of objects in a specific pattern Lets say you want to
>   place a bunch of objects in a grid or circle pattern. Traditionally
>   this would be done by either:
>
> Building an object completely from code. This is tedious! Entering
>   values from a script is both slow, unintuitive and not worth the
>   hassle. Make the fully rigged object, duplicate it and place it
>   multiple times in the scene. This is tedious, and placing objects
>   accurately in a grid is hard. So use Instantiate() with a Prefab
>   instead! We think you get the idea of why Prefabs are so useful in
>   these scenarios. Here’s the code necessary for these scenarios:

```
// Instantiates a prefab in a circle

public GameObject prefab;
public int numberOfObjects = 20;
public float radius = 5f;

void Start() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2 / numberOfObjects;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle), 0, Mathf.Sin(angle)) * radius;
        Instantiate(prefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}



// Instantiates a prefab in a grid

public GameObject prefab;
public float gridX = 5f;
public float gridY = 5f;
public float spacing = 2f;

void Start()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < gridY; y++) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridX; x++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, 0, y) * spacing;
            Instantiate(prefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the Hexagonal grid pattern?. This example does not follow the grid pattern, only place an element with specific rows and colums

Comment: see this or ask it in a new question please -> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-Hexagonal.html

Comment: Thanks for the link but I can't add prefab tiles to the tilemap. I try to create a Prefab Brush but with the Unity 2019.4 version doesn't have that option.

Answer (score 0):

Just to tack onto the great answer provided by Chico3001, the documentation does provide a very good explanation on how to make a wall using a block prefab. Replacing the block with a quaternion rotated 90 degrees on the x axis would create a flat tile, and adjusting the code so that you're using the z axis instead of the y axis will spread it out. Here is the code, [from the same section of the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html) Chico3001 referenced:

```
 using UnityEngine;
public class Wall : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject block;
   public int width = 10;
   public int height = 4;
  
   void Start()
   {
       for (int y=0; y<height; ++y)
       {
           for (int x=0; x<width; ++x)
           {
               Instantiate(block, new Vector3(x,y,0), Quaternion.identity);
           }
       }       
   }
}
```